# changing img size with screen.availWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery

so my code is:

```
var avW = screen.availWidth;

     if(avW <= "769px"){

             $.css({ height: '300px', });
      }
```

but  don´t think its correct, or maybe I'm missing something,  please help. thanks

Comment: what is `screen.availWidth`?

Comment: `avW` is going to be a numeric value, but this would be better solved using Media Queries

Comment: also tried: `$('body').resize(function(){});`

Comment: Tell us what you want, when and why to resize.

Comment: and including the first code inside the function  but isn't working, also changed the string conditional to `if(avW <= 769){}` but nothing happens either.

ps. tried the `@media screen and(min-width: 769){height: 300px;}` but  didn't work  I had never seen it but tried it anyways  but decided to go with  .js.

Comment: well,  I need an image to change size depending  on the screen's width,  thus  `$('body').resize(function(){
    var avWidth = screen.availWidth;
    
    if(avWidth <= 769){
     
     $('#IMAGE_1_SLIDE,#IMAGE_2_SLIDE,#IMAGE_3_SLIDE').css({
       height: '200px',
      });
    }
   });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `if(avW <= 769)`

`window.screen.availWidth` returns integer, not string.

**edit:**

You should use CSS media queries, like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px)
{
    #IMAGE_1_SLIDE,
    #IMAGE_2_SLIDE,
    #IMAGE_3_SLIDE
    {
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: just for curiousity, what is wrong with the js code ? i allready changed the error of string to integer but still not working
    
 `$('body').resize(function(){
    var avWidth = screen.availWidth;
    
    if(avWidth <= 769){
     
     $('#IMAGE_1_SLIDE,#IMAGE_2_SLIDE,#IMAGE_3_SLIDE').css({
       height: '200px',
      });
    }
   });`

Comment: I think it doesn't work, because `window.screen.availWidth` is related to screen reslution, not window size, so it doesn't change upon resize. Instead, use `window.innerWidth`. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrrbT/

Comment: + `$('body').resize()` won't work. We resize window so `$(window).resize()`